# Unencoding data from POST (CGI and C)

Tags: c, post, cgi

I was just reading this page http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html about getting started with CGI in C. I had a question about the code in the unencoding part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 80
#define EXTRA 5
/* 4 for field name "data", 1 for "=" */
#define MAXINPUT MAXLEN+EXTRA+2
/* 1 for added line break, 1 for trailing NUL */
#define DATAFILE "../data/data.txt"

void unencode(char *src, char *last, char *dest)
{
 for(; src != last; src++, dest++)
   if(*src == '+')
     *dest = ' ';
   else if(*src == '%') {
     int code;
     if(sscanf(src+1, "%2x", &code) != 1) code = '?';
     *dest = code;
     src +=2; }     
   else
     *dest = *src;
 *dest = '\n';
 *++dest = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
char *lenstr;
char input[MAXINPUT], data[MAXINPUT];
long len;
printf("%s%c%c\n",
"Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
printf("<TITLE>Response</TITLE>\n");
lenstr = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
if(lenstr == NULL || sscanf(lenstr,"%ld",&len)!=1 || len > MAXLEN)
  printf("<P>Error in invocation - wrong FORM probably.");
else {
  FILE *f;
  fgets(input, len+1, stdin);
  unencode(input+EXTRA, input+len, data);
  f = fopen(DATAFILE, "a");
  if(f == NULL)
    printf("<P>Sorry, cannot store your data.");
  else
    fputs(data, f);
  fclose(f);
  printf("<P>Thank you! Your contribution has been stored.");
  }
return 0;
}
```

I was wondering exactly how these lines:

```
else if(*src == '%') {
     int code;
     if(sscanf(src+1, "%2x", &code) != 1) code = '?';
     *dest = code;
     src +=2; }
```

convert something like %21 back into the exclamation mark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> else if(*src == '%') {
>   int code;
>   if(sscanf(src+1, "%2x", &code) != 1) code = '?';
>   *dest = code;
>   src +=2;
> }
> ```

If the string begins with a `%` character, `sscanf()` is used to parse the following hexadecimal characters. The `"%x"` format converts hexadecimal characters to a integer value (in this case, a character code), and the `2` specifies a maximum field width, so that it consumes *at most* 2 characters.

The return value of `sscanf()` indicate the number of successful conversions, so if it doesn't return `1`, it didn't find a valid hexadecimal number.

Then the character code is assigned to `*dest`, and the `src` pointer is advanced to point to the next character after the `%xx` sequence.

There are actually three bugs here:

1. The `"%x"` format specifier expects an argument of type `unsigned int *`. A `signed int *` was passed which, I believe, invokes *undefined behaviour*. Variadic functions (such as `sscanf()`) have unusal ways of passing the arguments, and it is required that the format specifier matches the type of the argument.

   However, the two types are similar enough that it will probably work just fine in practice.
2. It also accepts *signed* hexadecimal numbers (with a `+` or `-` character), which is probably not what the author intended.

   For example, `"%-ffText"` would result in `code == -15`.
3. The `src` pointer is advanced by 2 bytes, but `scanf()` doesn't necessarily consume 2 characters.

   `"%fText"` would result in `code == 15`, and consume only one character (other than the `%` character). The example above would consume 3 characters.

Comment: Thank you! Could you further explain the 3 bugs? I don't really understand the concept of unsigned vs signed int * and the issue that difference would cause. And in what cases would scanf() not consume 2 characters?

Also why does the author set the code = '?'. Just to put a ? before anything the unencoder doesn't understand. Acting as a flag I guess?

Comment: @rahc01: **1.** The compiler is given the freedom to behave arbitrarily when the programmer supplies an argument with incorrect type. In the case of `int` vs. `unsigned int`, it is unlikely to cause any problems beyond compiler warnings. **2.** `"%-ffText"` would results in `code == -15`. **3.** `"%fText"` would result in `code == 15` and consume 1 character (other than the `'%'` character). The code presumably produces a `'?'` character as a fallback character in case the conversion fails due to an invalid `"%xx"` sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The sscanf function translates 2 hex chars into a single int value. This value is equal to the ASCII value, therefore put in 'dest'. Since 2 chars has been decoded, src has to increase two positions.
So '%21' -> 0x21 -> char '!'